# Model retraining: reset state of optimizer or not?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, pre-training

I am retraining a neural net periodically with new datapoints that were collected. The initial training was performed using an Adam optimizer. My question is: when feeding a new batch of data to the pretrained model, should I reset the the state of the optimizer - in particular its learning rate that was obtained on previous data? After all, the learning rate that was obtained on previous data might be inadequate for the newly fed data. What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Why don't you do both (update and restart) and choose with CV.